# Stored Procedure Not Returning Data when adding second date

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, repository

I have this stored procedure that stopped returning rows when I added a ToDate parameter. Everything was working fine when it was just based off a From Date.

```
Create Procedure DailyHours(
@ToDate smalldatetime,
@FromDate smalldatetime
)AS
Begin
SELECT        
Hours, 
PayPeriod,
EmployeeName, 
RegHrs, 
OTHrs, 
DblHrs, 
PremHrs, 
DivDesc,
Description,
DATEPART(weekday, WorkDate) as WorkDay,
DATEPART(month, WorkDate) as WorkMonth,
DATEPART(wk, WorkDate)as WorkWeek,
DATEPART(year, WorkDate) as WorkYear
FROM EmployeeHours
inner join EmpDept on EmpDept.Dept = EmployeeHours.Dept
WHERE PayPeriod between @ToDate and @FromDate
order by Payperiod,WorkDay, DivDesc asc, Description asc, EmployeeName asc
END
GO
```

When I run this, it returns rows

```
SELECT        
Hours, 
PayPeriod,
EmployeeName, 
RegHrs, 
OTHrs, 
DblHrs, 
PremHrs, 
DivDesc,
Description,
DATEPART(weekday, WorkDate) as WorkDay,
DATEPART(month, WorkDate) as WorkMonth,
DATEPART(wk, WorkDate)as WorkWeek,
DATEPART(year, WorkDate) as WorkYear
FROM            EmployeeHours
inner join EmpDept on EmpDept.Dept = EmployeeHours.Dept
WHERE PayPeriod between '2020-04-13' and '2020-04-20'
order by Payperiod,WorkDay, DivDesc asc, Description asc, EmployeeName asc
```

The toDate and from Date are being passed through to here. When it hits the while, it jumps to return.

```
 public List<DailyHoursQuery> GetAllHours(DateTime toDate, DateTime fromDate)
    {
        var totalHours = new List<DailyHoursQuery>();
        {
            using (var cn = new SqlConnection(Settings.GetHrConnectionString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DailyHours", cn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToDate", toDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromDate", fromDate);
                cn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        var currentRow = new DailyHoursQuery()

                        {
                            Hours = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Hours"]),
                            PayPeriod = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["PayPeriod"]),
                            EmployeeName = Convert.ToString(dr["EmployeeName"]),
                            RegHrs = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["RegHrs"]),
                            OTHrs = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["OTHrs"]),
                            DblHrs = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["DblHrs"]),
                            PremHrs = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["PremHrs"]),
                            DivDesc = Convert.ToString(dr["DivDesc"]),
                            Description = Convert.ToString(dr["Description"]),
                            WorkDay = Convert.ToInt32(dr["WorkDay"]),
                            WorkMonth = Convert.ToInt32(dr["WorkMonth"]),
                            WorkWeek = Convert.ToInt32(dr["WorkWeek"]),
                            WorkYear = Convert.ToInt32(dr["WorkYear"]),
                        };
                        var something = "";
                        currentRow.ShortDate = currentRow.PayPeriod.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                        currentRow.PayPeriod = currentRow.PayPeriod.Date;
                        totalHours.Add(currentRow);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return totalHours;
    }
```

[repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFTUS.png)

I've dropped the previous stored procedure and recreated it with the new value.

```js
function getDailyHours() {
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#dailyHoursTable')) {
        $('#dailyHoursTable').DataTable().destroy();
    }
    $("#dailyHoursTable tbody").empty();
    var fromDate = $("#fromDateInput").val();
    var toDate = $("#toDateInput").val();
    $("#dailyHoursTableBody").empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/api/DailyHours/?fromDate=" + fromDate + "&toDate="+toDate,
        data: JSON.stringify({
        }),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                if (value.OTHrs !== 0 && value.DblHrs === 0 && value.PremHrs === 0) {
                    $("#dailyHoursTableBody").append(
                        '<tr>' +
                        "<td>" + value.ShortDate + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.Hours + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.EmployeeName + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.RegHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td style=\"background-color:yellow\">" + value.OTHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.DblHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.PremHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.DivDesc + " " + value.Description + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.WorkWeek + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.WorkDay + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkMonth + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkYear + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                    );
                }
                else if (value.OTHrs === 0 && value.DblHrs !== 0 && value.PremHrs === 0) {
                    $("#dailyHoursTableBody").append(
                        '<tr>' +
                        "<td>" + value.ShortDate + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.Hours + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.EmployeeName + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.RegHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.OTHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td style=\"background-color:yellow\">" + value.DblHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.PremHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.DivDesc + " " + value.Description + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.WorkWeek + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.WorkDay + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkMonth + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkYear + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                    );
                }
                else if (value.OTHrs === 0 && value.DblHrs === 0 && value.PremHrs !== 0) {
                    $("#dailyHoursTableBody").append(
                        '<tr>' +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.ShortDate +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.Hours +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.EmployeeName +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.RegHrs +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td" +
                        value.OTHrs +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.DblHrs +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td style=\"background-color:yellow\">" +
                        value.PremHrs +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.DivDesc +
                        " " +
                        value.Description +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.WorkWeek +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.WorkDay +
                        "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkMonth + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkYear + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                    );

                }
                else if (value.OTHrs !== 0 && value.DblHrs !== 0 && value.PremHrs === 0) {
                    $("#dailyHoursTableBody").append(
                        '<tr>' +
                        "<td>" + value.ShortDate + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.Hours + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.EmployeeName + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.RegHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td style=\"background-color:yellow\">" + value.OTHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td style=\"background-color:yellow\">" + value.DblHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.PremHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.DivDesc + " " + value.Description + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.WorkWeek + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.WorkDay + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkMonth + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkYear + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                    );
                }

                else if (value.OTHrs === 0 && value.DblHrs !== 0 && value.PremHrs !== 0) {
                    $("#dailyHoursTableBody").append(
                        '<tr>' +
                        "<td>" + value.ShortDate + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.Hours + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.EmployeeName + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.RegHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.OTHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td style=\"background-color:yellow\">" + value.DblHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td style=\"background-color:yellow\">" + value.PremHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.DivDesc + " " + value.Description + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.WorkWeek + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.WorkDay + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkMonth + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkYear + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                    );
                }

                else if (value.OTHrs !== 0 && value.DblHrs === 0 && value.PremHrs !== 0) {
                    $("#dailyHoursTableBody").append(
                        '<tr>' +
                        "<td>" + value.ShortDate + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.Hours + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.EmployeeName + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.RegHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td style=\"background-color:yellow\">" + value.OTHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.DblHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td style=\"background-color:yellow\">" + value.PremHrs + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.DivDesc + " " + value.Description + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.WorkWeek + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value.WorkDay + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkMonth + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkYear + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                    );
                }
                else {
                    $("#dailyHoursTableBody").append(
                        '<tr>' +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.ShortDate +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.Hours +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.EmployeeName +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.RegHrs +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.OTHrs +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.DblHrs +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.PremHrs +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.DivDesc +
                        " " +
                        value.Description +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.WorkWeek +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        value.WorkDay +
                        "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkMonth + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + value.WorkYear + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>");
                };


            });
            $("#dailyHoursTableHead").show();

            $('#dailyHoursTable').dataTable({
                serverside: true,
                paging: true,
                searching: true,
                responsive: true,
                colReorder: true,
                deferRender: true,
                scrollY: 600,
                scroller: true,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'columnsToggle',
                        exportOptions: {
                            // columns: ':visible' or
                            columns: ':visible'
                        },
                        columns: '.toggle'
                    },
                    'colvis',
                    {
                        extend: 'csv',
                        filename: 'Test',
                        text: 'CSV',
                        exportOptions: {
                            modifier: {
                                search: 'none'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible',
                            // columns: ':visible' or

                        },
                        title: function () {
                            var date = new Date();
                            var day = date.getDate();
                            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                            var year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(2);
                            var finalDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
                            return "All IT Open (" + finalDate + ")";
                        },
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                        text: 'PDF',
                        titleAttr: 'PDF',
                        customize: function (doc) {
                            doc.content[1].margin = [0, 0, 0, 0] //left, top, right, bottom
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            // columns: ':visible' or
                            columns: ':visible'
                        },
                        text: 'Excel',
                        filename: function () {
                            var date = new Date();
                            var day = date.getDate();
                            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                            var year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(2);
                            var finalDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
                            return "All IT Open (" + finalDate + ")";
                        },
                        //title: function () {
                        //    var date = new Date();
                        //    var day = date.getDate();
                        //    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                        //    var year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(2);
                        //    var finalDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
                        //    return "All IT Open (" + finalDate + ")";
                        //}
                    }
                ]
            });
            $("#returnedTable").show();
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            //$("#errorContainer").html('Something went wrong, unable to update this employee!');
            //$("#errorContainer").show().delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
            alert(ex.responseJSON.Message);
        }
    });
};
```

```html
@model IEnumerable<WEBCFS.MODELS.Queries.DailyHoursQuery>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.20/af-2.3.4/b-1.6.1/b-colvis-1.6.1/b-flash-1.6.1/b-html5-1.6.1/b-print-1.6.1/cr-1.5.2/fc-3.3.0/fh-3.1.6/kt-2.5.1/r-2.2.3/rg-1.1.1/rr-1.2.6/sc-2.0.1/sp-1.0.1/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.20/af-2.3.4/b-1.6.1/b-colvis-1.6.1/b-flash-1.6.1/b-html5-1.6.1/b-print-1.6.1/cr-1.5.2/fc-3.3.0/fh-3.1.6/kt-2.5.1/r-2.2.3/rg-1.1.1/rr-1.2.6/sc-2.0.1/sp-1.0.1/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/js/OperationsReports.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="margin:10px">
    <div>
        <label id="fromDate" for="fromDateInput" style="display: block">From Date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control" type="date" id="fromDateInput" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label id="toDate" for="toDateInput" style="display: block">To Date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control" type="date" id="toDateInput" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submitFromDate" onclick="getDailyHours()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="returnedTable">
    <table id="dailyHoursTable">
        <thead id="dailyHoursTableHead" style="display: none">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Pay Period
                </th>
                <th>
                    Hours
                </th>
                <th>
                    Employee Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Reg Hrs
                </th>
                <th>
                    OTH Hrs
                </th>
                <th>
                    Dbl Hrs
                </th>
                <th>
                    Prem Hrs
                </th>
                <th>
                    Department Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Week No
                </th>
                <th>
                    Day
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="dailyHoursTableBody">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mondays...

Switched the From and To Date around in the stored procedure and I'm good to go.